# Change the default value in SSRS parameter dyanamically based on other parameter value.

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I have a report with  `3 cascading parameters`. User-type, Region, District and Office. I have below requirement.
1. When the `user-type` is `Manager`, the user has to select the `Region, District and office` drop-down.
2. When the `user-type` is `District Manager`, the `Region` and `district` Drop-down need to filled with a `default` value `[first value from data-set]` and user has to select `office drop-down`.

So, the `default` values of the `other parameters` needs to be changed based on `user-type parameter` value. I have tried below in the default properties of `Region parameter`.

```
=iif(parameters!usertype.value = 'DM', first(Fields!RegionName.Value ,"RegionDataset"),nothing)
```

its gives following error..

> fields cannot be used in report parameter expressions.

Do we have any workaround in `SSRS` to set `dynamic default` values based on another parameter values?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to build a couple of datasets specifically for your default values, one for Region and 1 for District.

for example, let create a dataset called `dsRegionDefaults` and the dataset query might look something like this. (This is a little verbose but as I don;t know what your data looks like it's the best way to illustrate)

```
DECLARE @Regions TABLE (RegionID int, RegionName varchar(100))

IF @userType = 'Manager'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Regions
        SELECT RegionID, RegionName FROM myTable
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Regions
        SELECT RegionID, RegionName FROM myTable
            WHERE something = somethingelse
    END
SELECT * FROM @Regions
```

I know it seems like a lot more work but it's pretty quick to setup and easy to maintain, you also don't have to rely on the order of records in the dataset which could be asking for trouble in the future.

Comment: thanks. how we will handle the users without default value in parameters?

Comment: That depends on your database structure. Edit your post to show how default values are associated with users and I'll update the answer.